# Java Eclipse issuing a ClassNotFoundException while using AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate method from swingx-all-1.6.4.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, swingx

I downloaded swingx-all-1.6.4.jar from here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadswingxall164jar.htm, I added it to my Java Build Path in Eclipse. then I wrote java code using AutoCompleteDecorator such that:

```
...

import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator;

...

    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(myComboBox);
```

I do not have any issues by Eclipse about the code, it seems all written correctly, but when I run the application I get the following message

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/AutoCompleteDecorator    at
> DD_StartNewActivity.(DD_StartNewActivity.java:636)  at
> DD_StartNewActivity.main(DD_StartNewActivity.java:529) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
> ... 2 more

What's going wrong, please?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Run it how? From within Eclipse or from a Jar or what? It sounds like you don't have the jar on the classpath at runtime.

Comment: Run from within Eclipse. I will check for the classpath then, thank you